# Why isn't pop method working in my snake game

Tags: javascript, html

So here's is a very brief description on how my snake game works.
For loop is used to draw the snake.Newhead is an object, and after first iteration newhead is now the new element occupying the index 0 since we used .unshift() method to add newhead to the front of our snake array. To avoid having our new element obtain the same position during each iteration of the setInterval loop we add or increment the x coordinate by 20 (which affects the rect in the for loop later since snake[0] will now change ie the x will be 60 instead of 40 and snake[1] has taken the element of the old snake[0]) using snakex.
But what I don't get is why isn't snake.pop removing the last element or object in our array ie removing one rect from the snake

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var right = document.querySelector("right");
var left = document.querySelector("left");
var up = document.querySelector("left");
var down = document.querySelector("left");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 200;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

width = 20;
height = 20;

var snake = [{
  x: 40,
  y: 0
}, {
  x: 20,
  y: 0
}];

function move() {
  for (var i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    //lets just say i stands for index number
    ctx.strokeStyle = "orange";
    ctx.strokeRect(snake[i].x, snake[i].y, width, height);

  }

  snakex = snake[0].x;
  snakey = snake[0].y;

  snakex += 20;

  var newhead = {
    x: snakex,
    y: snakey
  };

  snake.pop();

  snake.unshift(newhead);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
}

setInterval(move, 800);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<button id="right">right</button>
<button id="down">down</button>
<button id="left">left</button>
<button id="up">up</button>
```

Comment: The `pop` is clearly working, as your `console.log(i)` only prints `0` and `1` ... Something is goes wrong at clearing the canvas ...

Comment: Ok so why isn't it working on the rects, it should be removing one rect each iteration

Comment: Because you only clear the area `(0,0, 20, 20)`  Ie the top-left corner ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is popping correctly, the issue is the clearRect call, you pass it width and height but those are set to 20, so only the top 20x20 are getting cleared, so you see al the frames printed on screen.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/vLxmws9d/

Edit: don't know why the SO snippet wasn't running so I used a jsfiddle instead.

```
var canvas= document.querySelector("canvas");
var right=document.querySelector("right");
var left=document.querySelector("left");
var up=document.querySelector("left");
var down=document.querySelector("left");

canvas.width=window.innerWidth;
canvas.height=window.innerHeight-200;
var ctx= canvas.getContext("2d");

width= 20;
height=20;

var snake=[{x:40, y:0}, {x:20, y:0}];

function move(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  for(var i=0; i<snake.length; i++){
    //lets just say i stands for index number
    ctx.strokeStyle="orange";
    ctx.strokeRect(snake[i].x, snake[i].y, width, height);
  }


  snakex=snake[0].x;
  snakey=snake[0].y;

  snakex+=20;

  var newhead={x:snakex, y:snakey};
  snake.unshift(newhead); 
  snake.pop();
}

setInterval(move, 800);
```

Comment: Thks for the help, I've fixed my problem

Comment: Actually, instead of clearing the whole canvas and redrawing the complete snake every time, I'd suggest to remove only the old tail and draw only the new head in each iteration. Because later in the game you surely want to have some obstacles at well. You will have to redraw all of them too. Which at some point (and if the snake is long enough) will result in a massive flickering of the whole screen ...

Comment: How do I remove the old tail

Comment: How do I remove the old tail

Comment: make a `clearRect()` at the exact coordinates of it

Comment: What @EdwinChigozie said is certainly a way of doing it, some game engines clear only things that change, but some others clear the whole screen every time. I think it'll be heavier to calculate what to clear and what to redraw instead of clearing everything and redrawing everything each frame. As for the flickering, I've done many things with canvas (from simulating a flag in the wind to particles), I alway clear everything each frame and never had any flickering issues.